# Access to method of another class in the same package is not possible

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I cannot access the static method of a class that is in the same package. I get the class name displayed in the auto-complete, but the method doesn't want to work.

I have already tried the following functionality of intellij without success.

"File" > "Invalidate Caches / Restart" > "Invalidate and Restart"

Method:

```
package de.elektriker_lifestyle.reducedcoffee;

import java.util.List;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.opencsv.*;

public class csvReader {

    private static final char SEPARATOR = ',';

    public static void updateCSV(String input, String output, String  replace, int row, int col) throws IOException {

        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(input),SEPARATOR);
        List<String[]> csvBody = reader.readAll();
        csvBody.get(row)[col]=replace;
        reader.close();

        CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(output),SEPARATOR,' ');
        writer.writeAll(csvBody);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    }



}
```

Here I want to use the method:

```
package de.elektriker_lifestyle.reducedcoffee;
public class test {
    csvReader.updateCSV(...);
}
```

Screenshots:

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/3AdDz.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpyzF.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzeOo.png

The following error appears "Cannot resolve symbol 'updateCSV'".

Comment: `csvReader.updateCSV(...);` should be inside some method

Comment: Also: pease please please do not start Java class names with lower-case letters.  (This will make you smell nicer, attract mates, feel better, and also win at cards.)

Comment: When in doubt about Intellij (e.g. going for "invalidate caches"), try building from the command-line, even in the command window within Intellij itself.  If the code compiles there and not in Intellij, then "invalidate caches" and other efforts may help.  If it doesn't compile there, then the problem is with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is not valid Java, you cannot call a method from the body of a class, a method call has to be part of some kind of initializer (such as a static field initializer or static block) or a method.

```
public class test {
    csvReader.updateCSV(...);
}
```

Comment: Try `public class test{ public void init() { csvReader.updateCSV(...); }`

Comment: This happens if you sit too long in front of the PC and the concentration decreases strongly. Such banality is overlooked. Thanks to SeanF and @ash

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the static method csvReader.updateCSV with all of the required arguments:

`csvReader.updateCSV("1", "2", "3", 4, 5);`

Use the code below as a guide:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader;
import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVWriter;

public class csvReader {

    private static final char SEPARATOR = ',';

    public static void updateCSV(String input, String output, String  replace, int row, int col) throws IOException {

        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(input),SEPARATOR);
        List<String[]> csvBody = reader.readAll();
        csvBody.get(row)[col]=replace;
        reader.close();

        CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(output),SEPARATOR,' ');
        writer.writeAll(csvBody);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            csvReader.updateCSV("1", "2", "3", 4, 5);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the previous answer states, you cannot call the method in the body of a class, all method executions should be inside another method this propagated until the main method.

Also the call you are doing is missing some parameters of your method declaration.

By last if you want your static method to get executed always on your class you should do it on the class constructor:

```
public class test {

   public test () {
    csvReader.updateCSV(...);
   }
}
```

`
That way each time a test object gets created your static method will get executed.

Answer (score -2):

import de.elektriker_lifestyle.reducedcoffee.csvReader.java in the test class above the public class test{}

Comment: Missing import isn't the problem.  And the import syntax is not correct.